# Disable sending texts on Android

Tags: android

I want to be able to have the user press a button in the app that disables sending texts.  In my googling attempts, I've seen that it might be impossible.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?  My thoughts are either to disable opening the texting app or just disable the send button in the texting app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not truly disabling it, as other comments have pointed out.  However... you could set up a service or some sort of polling period with an alarm.  You can check if a SMS app (you'll have to gather SMS packages) is open in the foreground by its package name, and then launch some activity from your application, essentially blocking the SMS app.

Granted, this is horrible UX and is very hacky, but it could work for preventing the sending of SMS by preventing the user from actually using any SMS apps.

Comment: okay thanks, I was looking for any sort of workaround, no matter how hacky

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, because "texting app" is a ***system application***, which have no open `API`'s for  it's UI customization. All you can do - just create custom texting application and replace with a system one.

Answer (score 0):

Even if one somehow found a way to disable the texting app, it does not account for the ContentProvider's that expose the SMS and MMS data to any app that asks for it nor the API's that allow any app that asks to do so to send SMS and MMS for you. This is why you can download alternative texting apps (and why hangouts recently turned into a combination sms/chatting app).

Sorry, but you're asking to do something that requires ripping out the guts of the OS, from what I understand.